# VBA Excel Running List of Alarm Messages Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba, message, alarm

I have a list of alarm messages, that I want to display in cell K5, depending on the value in cell H5. I have this code in the module.

```
Sub Display_Alarm_Descriptions()
    Dim alarmNumber As Integer, alarmMsg As String
    alarmNumber = Range("H5").Value
    If alarmNumber = 0 Then alarmMsg = "No Active Alarms"
    If alarmNumber = 1 Then alarmMsg = "Proofer Output Failure Safety"
    If alarmNumber = 2 Then alarmMsg = "Main Drive Overload"
    Range("K5").Value = alarmMsg

End Sub
```

What I would like to add is a running list of the timestamp when the value in H5 changes, what the new value of H5 is and the associated alarm message from K5. If H5 changes, I want the new information(time stamp, H5 value and alarm message) in the next available cells below.

Answer (score 1):

Easier this way:

```
<code>
Function AlarmDescriptions(Val As Integer) As String
    Dim alarmMsg As String

    Select Case Val
      Case 0
         alarmMsg = "No Active Alarms"
      Case 1
         alarmMsg = "Proofer Output Failure Safety"
      Case Else
         alarmMsg = "Main Drive Overload"
    End Select

    AlarmDescriptions = alarmMsg
End Function

Public Function Msg(Val As Integer) As String
   Dim Timestamp As Date

   Timestamp = Now
   Msg = Now & " - " & Val & " - " & AlarmDescriptions(Val)
End Function
</code>
```

Then from any cell, just type in formula: `=Msg(H5)`
and the message will display in that cell